# Is there any way to construct a function pointer by reading a file in c++

Tags: c++, c, file, function-pointers

I have a function prototype in a file. Is there any way to create a function pointer by reading the file at run time in c++?

Answer (score 2):

You are properly looking for [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/), from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libffi):

> libffi is a foreign function interface library. It provides a C
>   programming language interface for calling natively compiled functions
>   given information about the target function at run time instead of
>   compile time. It also implements the opposite functionality: libffi
>   can produce a pointer to a function that can accept and decode any
>   combination of arguments defined at run time.

Comment: Where can i find the details about libffi?

Comment: @user2599593 Check here [http://www.atmark-techno.com/~yashi/libffi.html](http://www.atmark-techno.com/~yashi/libffi.html)

Answer (score 0):

No. A function prototype is just a statement of how a function is used; it cannot be executed on its own.

If you have the name of a function and you want to turn that into a function pointer, you may be able to do so using [`dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "fn")`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html). Not recommended, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a system call (using the `system` function of the standard library) to invoke a compiler which creates a dynamic library from your function file. You can then load the library with `dlopen` or `LoadLibrary`, depending on the platform.

**EDIT:**
Of course this will not work if you really have only a prototype, and not the definition. In that case I am sorry I misunderstood your question.